# Image Post creates unusual extra HTML

Tags: editor

When I post an image using WordPress, I'm getting additional HTML being created which spills out after the image. E.g. see

http://www.snowcrash.eu/typing-pinyin-on-a-mac/

The HTML in Text Mode of the WordPress Editor is simply this:

```
<a href="http://www.snowcrash.eu/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Screen-Shot-2016-01-30-at-12.56.13-PM.png" rel="attachment wp-att-1252"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1252" src="http://www.snowcrash.eu/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Screen-Shot-2016-01-30-at-12.56.13-PM.png" alt="ABC Extended Input Source replaces US Extended" width="525" height="431" /></a>
```

which seems fine.

Any ideas why the WordPress Editor has added this unnecessary HTML?

Comment: What happens if you use _Add Media_ button in visual tab? You can also set link, size, alignment, title, alt text and everything else to image in there. Do you still get the same problem?

Comment: If that doesn't solve the issue, update your question and add all the code from _Text Mode_, there might be unclosed tags or violations of general `HTML` rules.

Comment: Something is adding a `srcset` attribute, and is incorrectly nesting an `<a />` tag (as opposed to just the URL) in the value. What happens when you use a default theme/disable all plugins?

Comment: My first guess would be that you have some rogue HTML in one of the image attribute fields of media manager.